# Selecting a random HTML element using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to select an element from my HTML code, to then use it in JavaScript (it needs to be highlighted). The HTML consists of a table with 36 td's.

My code so far:

```
var box;
function getRandom()
{
    return (Math.floor(Math.random()*37))
}
function highlight()
{
    box = document.getElementById(getRandom());
    box.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}
```

If anyone can give me any pointers, it'd be appreciated. I know it would be easy using jQuery, but I haven't begun learning that yet.
Edit: excerpt of the HTML code, this goes up to name="36".

```
<table id="reflexTable">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td name="1"></td>
      <td name="2"></td>
      <td name="3"></td>
      <td name="4"></td>
      <td name="5"></td>
      <td name="6"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Well, it simply does not work. My output console states that "box" is null. Sorry, I forgot to add that.

Comment: It helps if you write HTML. There is no `name` attribute for `<td>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementById` gets the element which has the matching `id`. Your table data cells don't have an id at all. They have a name, but HTML doesn't allow that.

Switch to id.

HTML 4 doesn't allow an id to start with a number. Prefix the id with a common string. Then:

```
document.getElementById("foo" + getRandom());
```

Comment: Thank you. Using "name" instead of "id" is probably a newbie mistake. Plus I didn't think of the fact that using a number as ID is prohibited.

Answer (score 5):

A nicer way that does not involve setting element ids:

```
function highlight() {

    // get all TDs that are descendants of table#reflexTable:
    var tds = document.getElementById('reflexTable').getElementsByTagName('td');

    // get a random int between 0 (inclusive) and tds.length (exclusive)
    var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * tds.length );

    // highlight td at that index
    tds[rand].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";

}
```

The big advantage of this method is that you can add/remove as many TDs as you please without needing to edit your JS to generate a valid random number.

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting the `id` attribute, you're setting the `name` attribute, change it to:

```
<td id="1"></td>
```

...etc

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

1. You should declare the box variable inside the highlight function.
2. You have to convert that random number to a string.
3. Quentin mentioned something important--you should give each table element an *id* of something like "s0","s1","s2", etc...
4. Start the naming at 0 because your getRandom function will sometimes return it.

function highlight(){
var number;
number = getRandom().toString();
var box;
box = document.getElementById("s" + number);
box.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}