# Select random row from table, then remove that row and create a new table with that row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found some code that helped me get pretty close. Kudos to [daiscog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595557/selecting-a-random-html-element-using-javascript-only/7600759#7600759) for that! Here is what I'm trying to do. There is a table with rows of entries for a giveaway. I want to be able to click a button and remove that row from the table and and generate a new table on the fly with that random row that was picked form the primary table.

Right now the code below selects a random row and highlights it in dark blue. Which is great. Issue is it also counts the `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` as rows in the random pick, ideally it wouldn't. Which isn't a huge deal. But can be once I get working what I'd like to. Issue is right now when the logs of entries gets really long it's hard to keep track of who was picked first.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this via Javascript?

```
    <table id="cp_logs_table" class="widefat" style="background-color:#333;color:#ddd;font-weight:bold;margin:15px;">
    <thead><tr><th scope="col">Name [Username]</th><th scope="col">Points</th><th scope="col">Entry Type</th><th scope="col">Time</th></tr></thead>
    <tfoot><tr><th scope="col">Name [Username]</th><th scope="col">Points</th><th scope="col">Entry Type</th><th scope="col">Time</th></tr></tfoot>
    <tr>
    <td title="wolfkin">wolfkin [wolfkin]</td>
    <td>- 150</td>
    <td>
    Lottery Ticket
    </td>
    <td title="2011-10-14 17:20:29">11 hours ago</td>
    </tr><tr>
    <td title="dragon290513">dragon290513 [dragon290513]</td>
    <td>+ 5</td>
    <td>
    Video Entry
    </td>
    <td title="2011-10-14 01:42:30">1 day ago</td>
    </tr></table>

            <script>
            function cplottopickwinner() {      
             // get all TRs that are descendants of table#cp_logs_table:
             var tds = document.getElementById("cp_logs_table").getElementsByTagName("tr");
             // get a random int between 0 (inclusive) and tds.length (exclusive)
             var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * tds.length );
             // highlight tr at that index
             tds[rand].style.backgroundColor = "#375297";
             //tds[rand].style.color = "#000";      
            }
            </script>

<a href="javascript:cplottopickwinner()">Pick Random Winner(s)</a>
```

I modified the function to the code below, but it's not populating the table with anything, but it's still highlighting the table row in blue. I'm sure I'm missing something simple to automatically remove that row and add it to the new table.

```
    function cplottopickwinner() {      
     // get all TRs that are descendants of table#cp_logs_table:
     var tds = document.getElementById("cp_logs_table").getElementsByTagName("tr");
     // get a random int between 0 (inclusive) and tds.length (exclusive)
     var rand = Math.floor( Math.random() * tds.length );
     // highlight tr at that index
     tds[rand].style.backgroundColor = "#375297";
     //tds[rand].style.color = "#000";       
     jQuery("#cb_winners").fadeIn("slow");
     var html = tds[rand].html();
     tds[rand].remove();
     jQuery("#winners").append("<tr>"+html+"</tr>");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have another table to put in the winners,

```
<table>
    <thead><!-- .... --></thead>
    <tfoot><!-- .... --></tfoot>
    <tbody id="winners"></tbody>
</table>
```

Then you just have to append the whole `<tr>` to it, then it will disappear from old table because it is not cloned.

```
document.getElementById('winners').appendChild(trs[rand]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sMPQS/

Comment: That was exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you, thank you! Only other thing I can think to have just for coolness factor is to be able to shuffle the table rows with a click before picking the winners. But this is GREAT. Love it. Thank you again.

Comment: One easy algorithm: Suppose you have 5 rows to pick, you can pick one of the first 5 rows randomly and send it to the end of the table, then you have 4 rows left to pick (the chosen one is now at the end of the table, so don't pick it again). Pick one of the first 4 rows and send it too, then you have 3 rows left to pick. Continue picking one row and send it to the end until you have no more rows to pick.

Comment: I actually used this jQuery plugin and it works great! http://mktgdept.com/jquery-shuffle

Answer (score 0):

I made it using jQuery.. hope it's helpful.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table id="cp_logs_table" class="widefat" style="background-color:#333;color:#ddd;font-weight:bold;margin:15px;">
    <thead><tr><th scope="col">Name [Username]</th><th scope="col">Points</th><th scope="col">Entry Type</th><th scope="col">Time</th></tr></thead>
    <tfoot><tr><th scope="col">Name [Username]</th><th scope="col">Points</th><th scope="col">Entry Type</th><th scope="col">Time</th></tr></tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td title="wolfkin">wolfkin [wolfkin]</td>
        <td>- 150</td>
        <td>Lottery Ticket</td>
        <td title="2011-10-14 17:20:29">11 hours ago</td>
        <td><input type='submit' value='MOVE' class='move'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td title="dragon290513">dragon290513 [dragon290513]</td>
        <td>+ 5</td>
        <td>Video Entry</td>            
        <td title="2011-10-14 01:42:30">1 day ago</td>
        <td><input type='submit' value='MOVE' class='move'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<script>
$('.move').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent('td').parent('tr');
    var html = row.html();
    row.remove();
    $('#winners').append("<tr>"+html+"</tr>");
});
</script>

<table id='winners' ></table>
```

Comment: I'm testing this out and it works great! Thanks for the reply. I would like to see this done automatically when I pick a winner at random. But his is pretty cool itself actually. Good job! I actually tweaked it a little so the #winners table is hidden by default and fades in when the first row is added.

Comment: Ohhhh I misread, thought you wanted clickable. Oops! Shouldn't be too hard to hack your randomization script into there.. ya?

Comment: Still learning jQuery so not sure how to tie it all together. But since the randomize script currently picks random rows out of all of them including the thead. That might automatically throw the thead tr in the new table.. mmm