# Selecting a Random HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a script to select a random element and change the css elements of it. They all have id's but are all the same as I used a function to make them.

```
const display = document.getElementsByClassName('display')[0];
function grid() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for(let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
             square = document.createElement('div');
            square.className = 'square';
            display.appendChild(square);
        }
    }
};

grid();
```

Above is the function I use to make the elements but I dont know how to make it so I can randomly select one of them.

Comment: "


Im trying to make a script to select a random element and change the css elements of it", I don't really understand the part with `css elements` can you be more specific? Post the HTML code too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595557/selecting-a-random-html-element-using-javascript-only

Comment: If by "They all have id's but are all the same" you mean that all the `id`s are the same, then that would be invalid HTML.

Comment: Judging by the provided code, I think Bmoney means that all **classes** are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of all your elements, which you can either do as part of `grid()`:

```
function grid() {
  const elements = [];
  for(..) {
    for(...) {
      const square = ...
      ...
      elements.push(square);
    }
  }
  return elements;
}

const squares = grid();
```

or you can just query-select them:

```
...
grid();
const squares = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`.square`);
```

After which "getting a random one" already has [Getting a random value from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array) as established answered post.

Answer (score 0):

## With plain JavaScript:

Plain JavaScript can seem a bit wordy/complicated to read through, but it's self-contained, so it's the best choice for developers with an aversion to using libraries.

```js
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
squares[Math.floor(Math.random() * squares.length)].style.background = "red";
```

```css
.square{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

## With Rando.js:

Rando.js makes the randomness simpler to read while also increasing the entropy of the randomness (so people can't predict what the next "random" result will be).

```js
rando(document.querySelectorAll(".square")).value.style.background = "red";
```

```css
.square{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>

<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

## With both Rando.js and jQuery (what I would do)

Rando.js handles the randomness while jQuery makes element selection and style editing simpler to read.

```js
rando($(".square")).value.css({background: "red"});
```

```css
.square{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://randojs.com/2.0.0.js"></script>

<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```